# Google Cloud Storage: Error 401: Invalid Credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I have tried running the dev server with `goapp serve` and `dev_appserver.py --default_gcs_bucket_name xxx.appspot.com  .`, but I always get the same error after calling `wc.Close()`.

Any ideas?

```
// test file
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./files/me.jpg")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

bucketName, err := file.DefaultBucketName(c)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

client, err := storage.NewClient(c)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer client.Close()

bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)
wc := bucket.Object("me.jpg").NewWriter(c)

if _, err = wc.Write(b); err != nil {
    return err
}

if err = wc.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(c, "Failed to close file", err)
    return err
}
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: the error is `unable to close bucket googleapi: Error 401: Invalid Credentials, authError`

Comment: solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and finally managed to solve the problem with the 2 simple following steps:

Authenticate my application with my credentials to be able to write on it.
$ gcloud auth application-default login

Run dev_appserver with the dev bucket name:
$ dev_appserver.py app --default_gcs_bucket_name [MY_DEV_BUCKET_NAME]

Replace MY_DEV_BUCKET_NAME by your actual bucket. You can create a new bucket just for dev.